# ASP Web API string parameter retrieves "null"

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

In `JavaScript` I have the following code:

```
var form = new FormData();
form.append("SomeParam", value);
...
```

Here when debugging I see `value is null`.

The service looks like this:

```
this.importNonSalaryPacketExcel = function (data) {
    return $http(
    {
        url: ...,
        method: "POST",
        data: data,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': undefined
        },
        transformRequest: angular.identity
    });
};
```

`Web API` code looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/front/file/importNonSalaryPacketExcel")]
public HttpResponseMessage ImportNonSalaryPacketExcel(ImportNonSalaryPacketExcelParam param)
```

And the object:

```
public class ImportNonSalaryPacketExcelParam
{
    public string SomeParam { get; set; }
    ...
```

Every field is assigned correctly except this one and it is being set to `"null"` rather than to `null`.

Can you help me identify possible problem?

Comment: Maybe because you expect `SomeParam` to be a string, use a `dynamic` type instead?

Comment: `SomeParam` is really a string but it should be assigned to `null` and not to string `"null"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the first simple solution is to check if param is `null` in `javascript` and not adding it to forms data at all.

The second problem is that there is custom media formatter involved `FormMultipartEncodedMediaTypeFormatter` which does not handle this case. I have just downloaded the source of the formatter and added support for this kind of situations.